# BPMN Diagrams not generated in report

Tags: enterprise-architect

I generate reports from EA, including diagrams.

BPMN diagrams are not reported where other diagrams are reported fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try into your documentation template. Select properties, and then look for the exclude filters. Ensure that the BPMN diagram types are not in the "Excluded Diagram Types" section.

If your document template uses fragments etc., then it could excluded in the main template, or in a fragment that is being called for the element type to which the BPMN diagram belongs.